# All chromium extensions throw errors since update to 13.10

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, 13.10

Since updating to 13.10 all chromium extensions generate errors:

```
chrome.extension is not available: 'extension' is not allowed for specified context type content script,  extension page, web page, etc.). [VM] binding (56):427
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sendRequest' of undefined include.preload.js:105
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onRequest' of undefined include.postload.js:473
GET http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js  superuser.com/:2047
GET http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.4.5&utms=2&utmn=590704726…n%3D(organic)%7Cutmcmd%3Dorganic%7Cutmctr%3D(not%2520provided)%3B&utmu=qQ~  ga.js:61

chrome.extension is not available: 'extension' is not allowed for specified context type  content script,  extension page, web page, etc.). [VM] binding (56):427
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onRequest' of undefined content.js:233
chrome.extension is not available: 'extension' is not allowed for specified context type         content script,  extension page, web page, etc.). [VM] binding (56):427
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onRequest' of undefined injected.js:169
chrome.extension is not available: 'extension' is not allowed for specified context type content script,  extension page, web page, etc.). [VM] binding (56):427
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getURL' of undefined content_js_min.js:5
GET http://engine.adzerk.net/z/8476/adzerk2_2_17_47  superuser.com/:1719
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'sendRequest' of undefined
```

How to fix this?

Comment: This seems the most relevant bug report, though it's kind of sparse on details: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=310609

Comment: Do you have adblock-plus installed? Beacause I was getting these errors from it. Once I uninstalled it everything went back to normal.

Comment: @karlingen: It's not specially related to adblock. As it states: EVERY extension throws errors.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige I see, but have you tried to remove adblock plus? Because my other extensions were throwing these errors until I removed Adblock Plus. Then they were not complaining anymore. 
Adblock Plus was apparently blocking some necessary functionality for other extensions.

Comment: @karlingen: I even uninstalled it. Seems not to be specially related to AdBlock in my case. I tried also several other extensions as the only extensions activated. Same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updating to ubuntu 13.10 also updated Chromium to 29.0.1547.65-0ubuntu2, breaking ALL of my Chromium plugins.

Using synaptic, do a 'complete removal' of the 'chromium-browser' which also uninstalls 'chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra'. Reinstall the prior stable version of Chromium 28 for ubuntu 13.04  (chromium-browser_28.0.1500.71-0ubuntu1.13.04.1_amd64.deb). The earlier versions of Chromium can be found at http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/google-chrome-stable. Download the appropriate **CHROMIUM** '.deb' file, 'right-click' to open with 'Ubuntu Software Center' and install.

All of my plugins/addons (Adblock Plus 1.6.1, AutoCopy 1.4.1, LastPass 2.5.5, Omnibox Timer 0.3.1) work again EXCEPT FOR 'Cool Clock' (ver 3.0.1.2).

Comment: This works, except that when I try to open Gmail now it crashes and I get the "Aw, snap!" screen. Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: @duxk.gh Yes, extensions work for me now but Gmail doesn't. Any luck figuring it out yet?

Comment: No. I switched to Firefox for now and have Chromium 29 installed. I'll check from time to time to see if the extensions in Chromium work again. For now Firefox is alright...

Comment: @MatthewAdams I started using Chrome 30 instead. Extensions work and no more crashes; see my answer below.

Comment: @duxk.gh, People who use chromium don't want to use chrome. They're better off using firefox, as it is open-source. Does anyone know if they're working on fixing this issue?

Comment: @Crake What a ridiculous thing to say. You speak for all Chromium users? I happen to be one and I prefer Chrome over Firefox. Besides, why not give people all options and let them decide for themselves?

Answer (score 5):

I just update Chromium browser to the version 30 (30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.10.2) and all problems were gone. The simplest method to upgrade Chromium browser to the version 30 is to use the [PPA for Ubuntu Mozilla Security Team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That's all, you can test now your upgraded browser - the problems with Chromium extensions should be disappeared.

Comment: I believe this is the easiest and the best solution. You don't have to remove anything, you don't have to downgrade anything, you get a more recent version and you get rid of the errors. Thanks Radu, I got everything working!

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs in Chrome v. 29

The solution is to upgrade to newer version, eg. 30 (or downgrade to 28 if you wish)

To check the version, type in the URL bar: `chrome://version`

First, you need to remove the current version (*your profile data will stay untouched*):

```
sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser
```

Then, install the new version. You may download installer package here:
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/ubuntu_mozilla_security/saucy/main/base/chromium-browser

(choose the version for your distro and architecture)

Once I had a link to the installer, this is how I installed the package for the x64 Saucy via the Terminal:

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.10.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i chromium-browser_30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.10.2_amd64.deb 
rm chromium-browser_30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.10.2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI: This problem is fixed today with latest official Chromium update (version 30) for Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 1):

For me downgrading to Chromium 28, [as suggested by John Littleton](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360954/all-chromium-extensions-throw-errors-since-update-to-13-10/361193#361193), caused Gmail and other Google websites to crash.

Instead, I have started using Chrome 30; all my extensions work and I don't experience any sudden crashes. To install Chrome you can add the PPA and install as follows:

Setup key:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Setup repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

Setup package:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install <package name>
```

where `<package name>` is the name of the package you want to install. I chose `google-chrome-stable` but there's also `google-chrome-unstable` and `google-chrome-beta`.

[Source (UbuntuUpdates.org)](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome)

Comment: No need to do anything manually - just download a package and dbl-click!: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/ . Chrome repositories will be added automatically. But I personally just gonna wait till they fix this one upstream.

Comment: Upgrading is the solution, but the code you provided does not work (outdated links)

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using SWIron port of Chromium, http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron.php for Ubuntu and there everything  works ok (the Chromium version of SWIron is same version as the broken one in latest Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of this ppa is made the errors disappear

https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/chromium-beta

Version 31.0.1650.39 Ubuntu 13.10 (231674)